# Where should I place ConcreteCommand in java packages hierarchy?

Tags: java, command, design-patterns, package

just implementing command pattern and wonder where should I place ConcreteCommand implementations in package hierarchy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Should I keep them close to Command, Receiver, or Client?

let's say app has this package structure

```
app.client.
app.services.
app.services.service1.
app.services.service2.
app.command.
```

I want to create commands for

```
app.services.service1.Service1 
app.services.service1.Service2
```

So where should I create those commands. Under app.command? or under app.client? or close to each service?

EDITED: with close I mean, under packages like

```
app.client.commands.
app.command.commands.
app.services.service1.commands.
app.services.service2.commands.
app.services.commands.
```

What is the best practice here?

I suppose it is more matter of style, so what is your opinion?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is used by the client and the service I would put it under neither. Instead I would use a different package or even a different module which they can both access.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the package name makes sense in every context it will be used, and is unambiguous, then it does not matter.